# How to get in_array values from multiple arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

My output is like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array (
 [type] => 1 
 [position] => main-widgets
 [key_position] => 3
 [code] => template/portfolio.inc 
) 
[1] => Array (
 [type] => 2
 [position] => main-widgets
 [key_position] => 3
 [code] => This is a code 
)
```

) `

How can I check if `in_array(Array[position]=='main-header'` Without using `foreach`?

This is my code:

```
if(in_array('main-header', array_column($PAGE['templates'], 'position'))) {
    $count = array_count_values($PAGE['templates']['position']);
    if($count['main-header']>1){
    echo 'multiple';
    foreach($PAGE['templates'] as $pos){
        if($pos['type'] == 1){
            require $base['basepath'].$pos['code'];
        }else {
            echo $pos['code'];
        }
    }
} else {
        echo 'Only 1';
        if($PAGE['templates']['type'] == 1){
            require $base['basepath'].$PAGE['templates']['code'];
        }else {
            echo $PAGE['templates']['code'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column()` or use the [PHP Implementation of array_column()](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php):

```
if(in_array('main-header', array_column($array, 'position'))) {
    //found
}
```

Or with `array_map`:

```
if(in_array('main-header', array_map(function($v) { return $v['position']; }, $array))) {
    //found
}
```

Comment: My php version is 5.4.35

Comment: OK downloaded the class from https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php

Comment: Added another option.

Comment: This just returns "1". What if found on multiple arrays? foreach is the only way? What i wanted is to find the arrays that in sub_array 'position' is the specific "title" and return the array values, or return to a variable

Comment: Totally different question.

Comment: OK, sorry for my terms and English..How could i do that, though?